# What is the meaning of "shantam papam"

Tags: sin, sanskrit

I have heard this phrase a number of times. Also have heard this in the Indian historical drama viz. Bharat Ek Khoj, wherein Dushyant wasn't able to recollect about Shakuntala, and Shakuntala claimed that she bore his son. At that very moment he says "**Shantam Papam**, do not try to malign my ancestors O Lady" What is the exact meaning of this words ? Is it a curse phrase or something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The scene](https://youtu.be/HoQm8c72Rxs?t=1410) you're referring to is adapted from Kālidāsa's play [Abhijñānaśākuntalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakuntala_(play)). 'śāntaṃ pāpaṃ' is the Sanskrit equivalent of 'god forbid' or 'heaven forbid'.

Here's how Monier Williams [explains](https://archive.org/details/sakuntalasanskri00kaliiala/page/204/mode/2up) it:

> 'Peace! a sin!' i.e., Silence! let me not listen to such sinful words; or, if no stop is placed after śāntaṃ, 'May the sin be palliated!' This seems to be the usual formula in the plays for averting the ill effects of blasphemous, malevolent, or lying words.

The same expression is also used in [Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga74/ayodhyaroman74.htm#Verse23):

> O cow, the well wisher of all! I hope there is no great panic from any quarter to us. For what occasion is your sorrow?
>
> Hearing the words of the intelligent Indra, the god of celestials, the prudent Kamadhenu (Surabhi) who was skilled in expressing words, replied as follows:
>
> ***śāntaṃ pāpaṃ** na vaḥ kiṃcit kutaścit amara adhipa* | 
> *aham tu magnau śocāmi sva putrau viṣame sthitau* || 2-74-23 
> *etau dṛṣṭvā kṛṣau dīnau sūrya raśmi pratāpinau* | 
> *ardhyamānau balī vardau karṣakeṇa sura adhipa* || 2-74-24
>
> **Heaven forefend that evil!** O, Indra the lord of celestials! There is no danger whatsoever to you from any quarter. Seeing these pair of bullocks, my sons, who are in hardship, being scorched by sun's rays, becoming weak, being troubled by the man who ploughs the land and being immersed in grief, I am pitiably weeping O, Indra!